# Calling a stored procedure from a silverlight webpart

Tags: silverlight-4.0, sharepoint-2010

I have created a silverlight webpart and I need to send an email when the form is submitted. I have written a sql stored procedure to send the mail. How can I can the stored procedure from silverlight web part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a WebService in your backend code that actually calls the stored procedure, and in your Silverlight app you call that webservice. Remember that Silverlight runs on the client (usually the browser), so any database access code should be done in the server, and access as a service.